# Change default conditional css class with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to style a text by its length. So true is red and false is green. I use ng-class with expression. It's possible to change the css after a user click?

This is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ndCqpZaALfOEiYieepcn?p=preview

```
<div>
 <p ng-class="{true:'green',false:'red'}[name.length>3 && toggle]">{{name}}</p>

 <p><b>Length: </b> {{name.length}} character(s)</p>

 <button ng-click="toggle=!toggle">Toggle class</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: don't you have to make a controller function for ng-click? Does inline code work?

Comment: No need for controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, `toggle` is undefined, which I think is causing an error when evaluating the expression `[name.length>3 && toggle]`. Then when you click the button, the opposite of `undefined` is true, so then your toggle starts working as you expect.

To fix this, you can use [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) to evaluate an expression before the views are processed.

For example, if you change your div to be:

```
<div ng-init="toggle = true">
```

then the class starts out as green initially.

Comment: In the documentation I never noticed this ng-init...Thanks a lot